# How to change word break mode in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, text

**Short story:** 
I want to enable `unix` word break mode in `Visual Studio` 2015.

**Long story:** I'm trying to switch from `Mono Develop` to `Visual Studio`, and have run back into one of the old problems. I use `ctrl + left` and `ctrl + right` a lot to select one word at a time in code, and apparently there is a `windows mode` that selects the space after the word *(if there is one)* and a `unix mode` that does not select the space. I in zero cases want to select the space automatically and so definitely always want to run in `unix mode`.

Does anyone know where this setting exists in `Visual Studio`? Or a way to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under *Tools -> Options* navigate to the **Text Editor** section and then go into *Behavior*. Under the **Navigation** section (should be the bottom/last one in the right-pane) you will see the option to choose VI mode (check box) and most importantly, the drop-down for switching between **Windows** & **UNIX** Word breaks.

Comment: I ended up not using VS prior to this answer was given due to personal preference. I have started using it now, though these options do not exist. Perhaps the answer is 2015 specific? I am running 2017 and there is no Behavior section, nor can I seem to search for any of the intended results.

Comment: I'll mark this as 2015, and ask again 2017 specific